# Can't Change the First Value in a Series Using Index as a Method in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, methods, series

The following code is giving me some unexpected output. In summary, I am defining a Dictionary (dict2) and then creating a series out of it. Then, I am re-assigning a new value to the Math course and the Science course using the Series' method. Only the value for Science changes (and for Math it is unchanged). Can you please help me understand why? Thank you.

Edit: My goal is to understand why this is not working as expected, rather than actually reassigning a value to Math. I've also added the code here instead of the screenshot. Thank you.

dict2 = {'Maths': 60, 'Science': 89, 'English': 76, 'Social Science': 86}

marks_series = pd.Series(dict2)

print(marks_series)

marks_series.Maths = 65

marks_series.Science = 90

print (marks_series)

Comment: Not reproducible. The values change as expected.

Comment: To modify the value of the dict, modify it in the form of subscript like `maeks_series['Maths'] = 65`

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the question @BigBen. Mechanic Pig, I am just hoping to understand why what I'm doing doesn't work - re-assignment of value to Math is not the final goal.

Comment: I just ran the same code in a different Python notebook and like @not_speshal said, it is not reproducible. It is so weird that in my original notebook it still doesn't work. Wondering if there is a memory related bug in the program.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted my notebook and that fixed the issue. I still wonder why it happened in the first place. But that's for another day.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to replays and info , your code working correctly and the problem may be case of importing pandas and your Env